# Weak adhesives, has some critical chemical been banned?

Tags: adhesion

I notice that in the last 10 years or so, the adhesives I encounter in everyday life have gotten noticeably weaker, is this because some critical chemical has been banned or regulated out of consumer products?

For example, the typical duct tape, packing tape, masking tape, and scotch tape that I can buy in stores now are all noticeably weaker and less adhesive than the same products 10-15 years ago. For example, duct tape used to a have thick, white adhesive that was extremely sticky, but duct tape that you would find in a hardware store now has a clear adhesive that is much less sticky.

I know that there other consumer products that have become inferior due to chemical banning; for example most plastic wrap is now made of HDPE plastic instead of the original polyvinylidene chloride, so it is greatly inferior to the original Saran wrap. Has the same thing happened to tape adhesives? If so, what is the operative chemical that has been banned?

Comment: How do you know that in the past tape was really stronger? How do you know that this is not just an impression you may have?